# Aurasma SDK issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, aurasma

I have integrated Aurasma SDK in my app for iOS. When I try to execute the SDK function it throws the following error:

> [AurasmaSDK] HTTP error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002
>   "unsupported URL"

I am using a key and a secret for that key. Key name contains space. Is that the issue?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? 
and please can you tell me how to get Aurasma SDK? 
I'm very new develpoer in AR world 
thanks so mush for any help!

Comment: Hi Rawan,
Request a new SDK from Aurasma without using space or special characters in the name of the SDK and it will solve the issue.